# Returning multiple values from subquery using CONCAT

Tags: php, mysql, sql, concatenation

I have a PHP/MySQL application

The application uses a query to get the values of a table `leads`, with 2 sub-queries to return the SUM and COUNT of values in a second table `refunds`

The 2 tables are linked with a foreign key `lead_id`

```
SELECT l.*,
       IFNULL(
                (SELECT SUM(amount)
                 FROM refunds r
                 WHERE l.lead_id = r.lead_id),0) amount_refunded,
       IFNULL(
                (SELECT COUNT(*)
                 FROM refunds r
                 WHERE l.lead_id = r.lead_id),0) number_refunded
FROM leads l
```

I would like to increase the performance of this query.

My thought was to:

1. Combine the the 2 sub-queries into a single sub-query using CONCAT
   with a pipe delimiter
2. Explode the returned string using PHP at the application level to
   get the 2 values.

Example below:

```
SELECT l.*,
  (SELECT CONCAT(IFNULL(COUNT(*),0),'|', IFNULL(SUM(amount),0))
   FROM fee_refunds r
   WHERE l.lead_id = r.lead_id) values_refunded
FROM fee_leads l
```

Then in the application, within the loop:

```
list($amount_refunded, $number_refunded) = explode('|', $row->values_refunded);
```

This approach works, however my questions are:

1. Is this bad form?
2. Is there any reason I should not do it this way?
3. Is there a better solution?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `join`!

```
SELECT l.*, r.amount_refunded, r.number_refunded
FROM leads l LEFT JOIN
     (SELECT lead_id, COUNT(*) as number_refunded, SUM(amount) as amount_refunded
      FROM refunds r
      GROUP BY lead_id
     ) r
     ON l.lead_id = r.lead_id;
```

You may find it faster, under some circumstances, to `join` before the aggregation.